# ActiveModelSerializer not serialize object nested children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonserializer

I have a model Category that use `awesome_nested_set` gem, so it has children of the model itself. I have created CategorySerializer for the model

```rb
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :parent_id, :lft, :rgt, :text, :permalink, :children

  def children
    object.children
  end
end
```

But children is not serialized. I have also tried add `has_many :children, serializer: self`, the result is this

```
{
        "id": 25918,
        "parent_id": null,
        "lft": 3,
        "rgt": 8,
        "text": "ARAG",
        "permalink": "25918-arag",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 25919,
                "parent_id": 25918,
                "lft": 4,
                "rgt": 7,
                "text": "Coperchi",
                "permalink": "25919-coperchi",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 25920,
                        "parent_id": 25919,
                        "lft": 5,
                        "rgt": 6,
                        "text": "Ribaltabili",
                        "description": "",
                        "page_title": "",
                        "meta_key": "",
                        "meta_description": "",
                        "key_1": null,
                        "key_2": null,
                        "key_3": null,
                        "extra": null,
                        "created_at": "2019-03-01T21:08:15.000+01:00",
                        "updated_at": "2019-04-02T12:27:05.000+02:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Second level of children is successfully serialized but it children is not. Is there a way or alternative to serialize all object children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want **deep nesting by default**, then you can set following config property in the initializer file

```
# config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb    
ActiveModelSerializers.config.default_includes = '**
```

For more details, you can check [this](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/adapters.md#include-option).

You can also add another serializer for children as follow

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :parent_id, :lft, :rgt, :text, :permalink, :children

  def children
    ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(object.children,  each_serializer: ChildrenSerializer)
  end
end
```

For more information, you can refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@stellamarisnjage/serializing-deeply-nested-associations-in-rails-2173d588c528)

Comment: The second option is actually worked! I have also tried this before but by using `each_serializer: self` it return error `undefined method `new' for #<CategorySerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution with invoking serializer on children? Be careful to not get into infinite loop with deep nesting

```
def children
  object.children.map { |obj| SomeSerializer.new(obj) }
end
```